# using - if( isNaN( ) ) ) to find an replace

Tags: jquery

I've got a little calculator that I want to configure CSS Margin Shorthand to %

I'm currently getting the user to input the numbers in a form on which I then seperate each number and 'do the maths' to it.

I want it to ignore any NaN when the user uses CSS shorthand.

I've currently got this -

```
  if( isNaN( parseInt(margins || paddings ) ) )
       alert(" Please re-enter your age.");
```

which works but I want to change the "alert" bit to just ignore/replace the NaN with nothing.

Any ideas?

here's a link to my JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sturobson/reCjA/8/

I don't want the NaN's to appear if the user hasn't submitted any numbers

Comment: could you show some more code...!

Comment: edit the q. a link to some code - http://jsfiddle.net/sturobson/reCjA/8/

Comment: what should be displayed if NaN...

Comment: nothing, if the result is NaN i don't want to see NaN in the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm.. pretty trivial.

```
if (isNaN(parseInt(margins || paddings))) {
    //do nothing.
}
```

Another option, opposite direction:

```
if(!isNaN(parseInt(margins || paddings))) {
    //do something
}
```

After seeing your edit, looks like what you need is custom function that wrap `parseInt`, returning empty string if not valid number:

```
function GetIntOrEmpty(value) {
    var result = parseInt(value, 10);
    return isNaN(result) ? "" : result + "";
}
```

Then just call this instead of `parseInt` and also move all the calculations to be "inside" the function call, as doing math with strings is not good idea.

For example:

```
//OTHER RESULT CALCULATIONS
var result4 = GetIntOrEmpty(num4* 2);
var result7 = GetIntOrEmpty(num5 * 2);
var result8 = GetIntOrEmpty(num3 * 2);
var resulta = GetIntOrEmpty(num1 - result8 - result4 - result7);
var result3 = GetIntOrEmpty(num1 - result4);
var result5 = GetIntOrEmpty(num4 / num1 * 100);
var result6 = GetIntOrEmpty(num5 / num1 * 100);
var result = GetIntOrEmpty(resulta / num2 * 100);
var result2 = GetIntOrEmpty(num1 - num3);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/reCjA/15/).

Comment: I want it so that if there is a NaN for there to be 'nothing' in the resulting HTML - please see my edited question with link to JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question, can't you do something like:

```
if( isNaN( parseInt(margins || paddings ) ) ) {
    alert(" Please re-enter your age.");
    return false;
}
```